# httpurlconnection.getoutputstream() takes 2 minutes

Tags: android, httpconnection

Here is my code:

```
public class HttpClient {
public String AddressBase = "";

String _AccessToken = "";
String _AccessToken = "";

public HttpClient() {
}

public HttpClient(String accessToken) {
    _AccessToken = accessToken;
}

private HttpURLConnection  _CreateConnection(String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params) throws IOException {
    Uri.Builder uriB1 = Uri.parse(AddressBase).buildUpon()
            .appendEncodedPath(url);
    if (params != null)
        for (Pair<String, String> p :
                params) {
            uriB1 = uriB1.appendQueryParameter(p.first, p.second);
        }
    URL callUrl = new URL(uriB1.build().toString());
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) callUrl.openConnection();
    if (!_AccessToken.isEmpty())
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + _AccessToken);
    return connection;
}

private <T, Y> Y _Post(final String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params, final T object, final Class<Y> objectClass) {
    Log.e("check net", "_post");
    return _Post(url, params, AppConstants.Gson_Get().toJson(object), "application/json", objectClass);
}

private <Y> Y _Post(final String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params, final String postBodyContent, String postBodyContentType, final Class<Y> objectClass) {
    Y r = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        Log.e("tag", " try create connection");
        connection = _CreateConnection(url, params);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", postBodyContentType);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        if (postBodyContent != null && !postBodyContent.isEmpty()) {
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            wr.write(postBodyContent);
            wr.flush();
        }
        connection.connect();
        Log.e("tag", "  connection connected");

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            String h1 = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding");
            if (h1 != null && h1.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
            }
            String resultString = _ConvertStreamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            r = AppConstants.Gson_Get().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    return r;
}

private String _ConvertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    Log.e("checknet", "cnovert stram to string");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

public <T, Y> Y Post(final String url, final T object, final Class<Y> objectClass) {
    return _Post(url, null, object, objectClass);
}

public <T> T PostParamsInQuery(String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params, final Class<T> objectClass) {
    return _Post(url, params, null, "application/json", objectClass);
}

public <T> T PostParamsInBody(String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params, final Class<T> objectClass) {
    StringBuilder postBodyContent = new StringBuilder("");
    for (Pair<String, String> p :
            params) {
        try {
            if (postBodyContent.length() != 0)
                postBodyContent.append('&');
            postBodyContent.append(URLEncoder.encode(p.first, "UTF-8"));
            postBodyContent.append("=");
            postBodyContent.append(URLEncoder.encode(p.second, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return _Post(url, null, postBodyContent.toString(), "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", objectClass);
}

public <T> T Get(String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params, final Class<T> objectClass) {
    T r = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = _CreateConnection(url, params);
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            if (connection.getHeaderField("Content-Encoding").equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
            }
            String resultString = _ConvertStreamToString(inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            r = AppConstants.Gson_Get().fromJson(resultString, objectClass);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    return r;
}

public boolean Delete(String url, final ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> params) {
    boolean r = false;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = _CreateConnection(url, params);
        connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        r = connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
    if (connection != null)
        connection.disconnect();
    return r;
}

public <T, Y> Y InvokeApi(String apiName, final T arg, Class<Y> returnClass) {
    return Post(String.format("/api/%s", apiName), arg, returnClass);
}

public <T, Y> void InvokeApiAsync(final String apiName, final T arg, final Class<Y> returnClass, final ActionListener<Y> listener) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Y>() {
        @Override
        protected Y doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return InvokeApi(apiName, arg, returnClass);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Y result) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.Action(result);
            }

        }
    }.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 }

}
```

When I call `InvokeApiAsync` it takes long time about 3 minutes to get response because of .getoutputstream(). I've been using AsyncTask for parallel connection too.I dont know what to do anymore I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem before, check your network (perhaps WiFi) proxy on your device that you test your code on!

Android tries to connect to the proxy and if it fails (incorrect proxy or very slow one) it will wait for a long time (default) to get the outputStream.

Either turn the proxy off or set the time out to smaller value to get the timeout exception sooner!

Answer (score 0):

You had better use an IntentService instead of AsyncTask for API connections.

Comment: I think google said to use AsyncTask but thank you for your answer